# Angular 5 HTTP failure during parsing for image

Tags: angular, image, http, parsing, express

I want to get image from Express server with Angular using its filename:

[Request from Angular service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oKqR.png)

And I want to send the file back to the client:

[Sending file from Express server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNhB2.png)

When I log the response from the server I get the following error:

[Error message from response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHHEa.png)

I am nearly sure that I am missing any options either in my request or in my response, but I am not sure what.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HttpClient applay 'json()' method to the respond so if your respond is non-JSON data you will get this kind of error.

Although it’s the most common, sometimes you’ll deal with different sorts of data. This is supported via the responseType property.

```
this.http.get('...', { responseType: 'text' }); //
```

> responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'

Comment: Yup, it looks like I was missing the response type. After I added { response type: 'blob' } everything started working correctly. Now I receive my image as a Blob file. Any ideas how to display it in the HTML ?